# Tables in appendix

Tags: tables, thesis

I have the following data to be put into appendix of [this thesis template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/iit-kharagpur-phd-thesis-template/cbncrndtqkzz).

I need the entire table to be in one page but on compilation, it comes towards one side.
I have 100s such tables that need to put into the appendix.

MWE is given below:

```
\begin{table*}[htp]
    \centering
    \caption{Log of IUE observations of NGC 451}
    \label{Log 451a} 
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=1.05\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{cccccccccccc}
            \hline 
Spectrum    &   J.D. start  &   Date of Obs.    &   U.T.    &   Spectrum    &   J.D. start  &   Date of Obs.    &   U.T.    \\ \hline
            
Spectrum    &   J.D. start  &   Date of Obs.    &   U.T.    &   Spectrum    &   J.D. start  &   Date of Obs.    &   U.T.    \\ \hline
        
        So49381&    2449322.75 &    12/01/1993& 05:44:16&   So49494&    2449328.67 &    12/07/1993& 03:48:08    \\
        
        So49382&    2449322.79 &    12/01/1993& 06:54:02&   So49496&    2449328.75 &    12/07/1993& 05:49:52    \\
        
        So49392&    2449323.34 &    12/01/1993& 20:05:43&   So49497&    2449328.79 &    12/07/1993& 06:51:00    \\
        
        So49393&    2449323.39 &    12/01/1993& 21:07:48&   So49498&    2449328.84 &    12/07/1993& 07:58:49    \\
        
        Lo26861&    2449323.55 &    12/02/1993& 01:10:08&   So49507&    2449329.25 &    12/07/1993& 17:56:42    \\
        
        Lo26864&    2449323.70 &    12/02/1993& 04:41:27&   So49509&    2449329.35 &    12/07/1993& 20:09:02    \\
        
        So49395&    2449323.58 &    12/02/1993& 01:41:56&   Lo26978&    2449329.72 &    12/08/1993& 05:10:48    \\
        
        So49397&    2449323.68 &    12/02/1993& 04:06:15&   Lo26980&    2449329.80 &    12/08/1993& 07:11:39    \\
        
        So49398&    2449323.73 &    12/02/1993& 05:17:21&   Lo26989&    2449330.23 &    12/08/1993& 17:23:20    \\
        
        So49399&    2449323.78 &    12/02/1993& 06:29:06&   Lo26992&    2449330.37 &    12/08/1993& 20:43:49    \\
        
        So49400&    2449323.82 &    12/02/1993& 07:32:56&   Lo26993&    2449330.41 &    12/08/1993& 21:46:46    \\
        
        So49409&    2449324.29 &    12/02/1993& 18:53:34&   So49514&    2449329.61 &    12/08/1993& 02:34:04    \\
        
        So49412&    2449324.42 &    12/02/1993& 21:58:54&   So49516&    2449329.70 &    12/08/1993& 04:35:52    \\
        
        Lo26880&    2449324.58 &    12/03/1993& 01:52:08&   So49518&    2449329.78 &    12/08/1993& 06:39:15    \\
        
        Lo26893&    2449325.23 &    12/03/1993& 17:25:31&   So49519&    2449329.83 &    12/08/1993& 07:49:13    \\
        
        Lo26896&    2449325.37 &    12/03/1993& 20:50:35&   So49527&    2449330.21 &    12/08/1993& 16:54:10    \\
        
        So49415&    2449324.65 &    12/03/1993& 03:28:00&   Lo27008&    2449331.23 &    12/09/1993& 17:27:06    \\
        
        So49416&    2449324.70 &    12/03/1993& 04:31:01&   Lo27010&    2449331.32 &    12/09/1993& 19:38:06    \\
        
        So49418&    2449324.79 &    12/03/1993& 06:39:48&   So49533&    2449330.53 &    12/09/1993& 00:31:51    \\
        
        So49419&    2449324.84 &    12/03/1993& 07:58:12&   So49534&    2449330.57 &    12/09/1993& 01:27:21    \\
        
        Lo26899&    2449325.61 &    12/04/1993& 02:26:16&   So49538&    2449330.75 &    12/09/1993& 05:45:08    \\
        
        Lo26900&    2449325.65 &    12/04/1993& 03:32:35&   So49539&    2449330.79 &    12/09/1993& 06:47:53    \\
        
        Lo26915&    2449326.36 &    12/04/1993& 20:40:35&   So49547&    2449331.21 &    12/09/1993& 16:56:54    \\
        
        So49431&    2449325.54 &    12/04/1993& 00:52:25&   So49548&    2449331.26 &    12/09/1993& 17:56:41    \\
        
        So49432&    2449325.59 &    12/04/1993& 01:52:29&   So49550&    2449331.35 &    12/09/1993& 20:08:02    \\
        
        So49434&    2449325.68 &    12/04/1993& 04:02:52&   So49551&    2449331.39 &    12/09/1993& 21:05:29    \\
        
        So49435&    2449325.72 &    12/04/1993& 05:04:28&   Lo27015&    2449331.62 &    12/10/1993& 02:54:11    \\
        
        So49446&    2449326.26 &    12/04/1993& 17:57:50&   So49554&    2449331.56 &    12/10/1993& 01:14:37    \\
        
        So49447&    2449326.30 &    12/04/1993& 19:00:19&   So49555&    2449331.60 &    12/10/1993& 02:19:19    \\
        
        So49450&    2449326.55 &    12/05/1993& 00:57:09&   So49557&    2449331.69 &    12/10/1993& 04:27:56    \\
        
        So49453&    2449326.67 &    12/05/1993& 03:58:31&   So49558&    2449331.74 &    12/10/1993& 05:33:43    \\
        
        So49454&    2449326.71 &    12/05/1993& 04:59:49&   So49560&    2449331.85 &    12/10/1993& 08:18:41    \\
        
        So49455&    2449326.76 &    12/05/1993& 06:00:24&   Lo27025&    2449332.83 &    12/11/1993& 07:42:12    \\
        
        So49464&    2449327.23 &    12/05/1993& 17:15:18&   So49567&    2449332.76 &    12/11/1993& 05:57:11    \\
        
        So49466&    2449327.32 &    12/05/1993& 19:32:32&   So49333&    2449318.84 &    27/11/1993& 07:52:24    \\
        
        So47760&    2449135.85 &    28/05/1993& 08:17:37&   So49363&    2449320.89 &    29/11/1993& 09:08:14    \\
        
        So47761&    2449135.89 &    28/05/1993& 09:13:25&   Lo26832&    2449320.91 &    29/11/1993& 09:43:00    \\
        
        So49343&    2449319.91 &    28/05/1993& 09:35:26&   So49373&    2449321.88 &    30/11/1993& 08:57:37    \\
        
        Lo25616&    2449135.87 &    28/05/1993& 08:42:59&   So49374&    2449321.93 &    30/11/1993& 10:02:20    \\
        
        Lo26937&    2449327.64 &    12/06/1993& 03:16:57&   Lo26838&    2449321.95 &    30/11/1993& 10:35:13    \\
        
        So49470&    2449327.54 &    12/06/1993& 00:41:47&   Lo27034&    2449334.77 &    13/12/1993& 06:18:55    \\
        
        So49472&    2449327.62 &    12/06/1993& 02:44:03&   Lo27035&    2449334.81 &    13/12/1993& 07:20:59    \\
        
        So49474&    2449327.71 &    12/06/1993& 04:48:10&   So49582&    2449334.75 &    13/12/1993& 05:50:03    \\
        
        So49475&    2449327.75 &    12/06/1993& 05:52:24&   So49583&    2449334.79 &    13/12/1993& 06:49:05    \\
        
        So49476&    2449327.79 &    12/06/1993& 06:53:05&   Lo27041&    2449335.81 &    14/12/1993& 07:14:49    \\
        
        So49486&    2449328.27 &    12/06/1993& 18:23:43&   So49592&    2449335.75 &    14/12/1993& 05:42:29    \\
        
        So49487&    2449328.32 &    12/06/1993& 19:28:24&   Lo27048&    2449336.77 &    15/12/1993& 06:18:25    \\
        
        Lo26954&    2449328.56 &    12/07/1993& 01:16:10&   So49601&    2449336.79 &    15/12/1993& 06:46:47    \\
        
        Lo26971&    2449329.32 &    12/07/1993& 19:39:00&   &   &   &       \\
        
        \hline      %inserts single line
        \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{table*}
```

Error on using

```
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
```

[image: error]

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages.

Comment: I'm not understanding your problem.  What do you mean by "it comes to one side"?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[htp]%
    \centering%
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.92}%
    \caption{Log of IUE observations of NGC 451}
    \label{Log 451a}
%    \begin{adjustbox}{width=1.05\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{cccc @{\qquad} cccc}
            \toprule
Spectrum    &   J.D. start  &   Date of Obs.    &   U.T.    &  
Spectrum    &   J.D. start  &   Date of Obs.    &   U.T.    \\
        \midrule

        So49381&    2449322.75 &    12/01/1993& 05:44:16&   So49494&    2449328.67 &    12/07/1993& 03:48:08    \\

        So49382&    2449322.79 &    12/01/1993& 06:54:02&   So49496&    2449328.75 &    12/07/1993& 05:49:52    \\

        So49392&    2449323.34 &    12/01/1993& 20:05:43&   So49497&    2449328.79 &    12/07/1993& 06:51:00    \\

        So49393&    2449323.39 &    12/01/1993& 21:07:48&   So49498&    2449328.84 &    12/07/1993& 07:58:49    \\

        Lo26861&    2449323.55 &    12/02/1993& 01:10:08&   So49507&    2449329.25 &    12/07/1993& 17:56:42    \\
    \addlinespace
        Lo26864&    2449323.70 &    12/02/1993& 04:41:27&   So49509&    2449329.35 &    12/07/1993& 20:09:02    \\

        So49395&    2449323.58 &    12/02/1993& 01:41:56&   Lo26978&    2449329.72 &    12/08/1993& 05:10:48    \\

        So49397&    2449323.68 &    12/02/1993& 04:06:15&   Lo26980&    2449329.80 &    12/08/1993& 07:11:39    \\

        So49398&    2449323.73 &    12/02/1993& 05:17:21&   Lo26989&    2449330.23 &    12/08/1993& 17:23:20    \\

        So49399&    2449323.78 &    12/02/1993& 06:29:06&   Lo26992&    2449330.37 &    12/08/1993& 20:43:49    \\
    \addlinespace
        So49400&    2449323.82 &    12/02/1993& 07:32:56&   Lo26993&    2449330.41 &    12/08/1993& 21:46:46    \\

        So49409&    2449324.29 &    12/02/1993& 18:53:34&   So49514&    2449329.61 &    12/08/1993& 02:34:04    \\

        So49412&    2449324.42 &    12/02/1993& 21:58:54&   So49516&    2449329.70 &    12/08/1993& 04:35:52    \\

        Lo26880&    2449324.58 &    12/03/1993& 01:52:08&   So49518&    2449329.78 &    12/08/1993& 06:39:15    \\

        Lo26893&    2449325.23 &    12/03/1993& 17:25:31&   So49519&    2449329.83 &    12/08/1993& 07:49:13    \\
    \addlinespace
        Lo26896&    2449325.37 &    12/03/1993& 20:50:35&   So49527&    2449330.21 &    12/08/1993& 16:54:10    \\

        So49415&    2449324.65 &    12/03/1993& 03:28:00&   Lo27008&    2449331.23 &    12/09/1993& 17:27:06    \\

        So49416&    2449324.70 &    12/03/1993& 04:31:01&   Lo27010&    2449331.32 &    12/09/1993& 19:38:06    \\

        So49418&    2449324.79 &    12/03/1993& 06:39:48&   So49533&    2449330.53 &    12/09/1993& 00:31:51    \\

        So49419&    2449324.84 &    12/03/1993& 07:58:12&   So49534&    2449330.57 &    12/09/1993& 01:27:21    \\
    \addlinespace
        Lo26899&    2449325.61 &    12/04/1993& 02:26:16&   So49538&    2449330.75 &    12/09/1993& 05:45:08    \\

        Lo26900&    2449325.65 &    12/04/1993& 03:32:35&   So49539&    2449330.79 &    12/09/1993& 06:47:53    \\

        Lo26915&    2449326.36 &    12/04/1993& 20:40:35&   So49547&    2449331.21 &    12/09/1993& 16:56:54    \\

        So49431&    2449325.54 &    12/04/1993& 00:52:25&   So49548&    2449331.26 &    12/09/1993& 17:56:41    \\

        So49432&    2449325.59 &    12/04/1993& 01:52:29&   So49550&    2449331.35 &    12/09/1993& 20:08:02    \\
    \addlinespace
        So49434&    2449325.68 &    12/04/1993& 04:02:52&   So49551&    2449331.39 &    12/09/1993& 21:05:29    \\

        So49435&    2449325.72 &    12/04/1993& 05:04:28&   Lo27015&    2449331.62 &    12/10/1993& 02:54:11    \\

        So49446&    2449326.26 &    12/04/1993& 17:57:50&   So49554&    2449331.56 &    12/10/1993& 01:14:37    \\

        So49447&    2449326.30 &    12/04/1993& 19:00:19&   So49555&    2449331.60 &    12/10/1993& 02:19:19    \\

        So49450&    2449326.55 &    12/05/1993& 00:57:09&   So49557&    2449331.69 &    12/10/1993& 04:27:56    \\
    \addlinespace
        So49453&    2449326.67 &    12/05/1993& 03:58:31&   So49558&    2449331.74 &    12/10/1993& 05:33:43    \\

        So49454&    2449326.71 &    12/05/1993& 04:59:49&   So49560&    2449331.85 &    12/10/1993& 08:18:41    \\

        So49455&    2449326.76 &    12/05/1993& 06:00:24&   Lo27025&    2449332.83 &    12/11/1993& 07:42:12    \\

        So49464&    2449327.23 &    12/05/1993& 17:15:18&   So49567&    2449332.76 &    12/11/1993& 05:57:11    \\

        So49466&    2449327.32 &    12/05/1993& 19:32:32&   So49333&    2449318.84 &    27/11/1993& 07:52:24    \\
    \addlinespace
        So47760&    2449135.85 &    28/05/1993& 08:17:37&   So49363&    2449320.89 &    29/11/1993& 09:08:14    \\

        So47761&    2449135.89 &    28/05/1993& 09:13:25&   Lo26832&    2449320.91 &    29/11/1993& 09:43:00    \\

        So49343&    2449319.91 &    28/05/1993& 09:35:26&   So49373&    2449321.88 &    30/11/1993& 08:57:37    \\

        Lo25616&    2449135.87 &    28/05/1993& 08:42:59&   So49374&    2449321.93 &    30/11/1993& 10:02:20    \\

        Lo26937&    2449327.64 &    12/06/1993& 03:16:57&   Lo26838&    2449321.95 &    30/11/1993& 10:35:13    \\
    \addlinespace
        So49470&    2449327.54 &    12/06/1993& 00:41:47&   Lo27034&    2449334.77 &    13/12/1993& 06:18:55    \\

        So49472&    2449327.62 &    12/06/1993& 02:44:03&   Lo27035&    2449334.81 &    13/12/1993& 07:20:59    \\

        So49474&    2449327.71 &    12/06/1993& 04:48:10&   So49582&    2449334.75 &    13/12/1993& 05:50:03    \\

        So49475&    2449327.75 &    12/06/1993& 05:52:24&   So49583&    2449334.79 &    13/12/1993& 06:49:05    \\

        So49476&    2449327.79 &    12/06/1993& 06:53:05&   Lo27041&    2449335.81 &    14/12/1993& 07:14:49    \\
    \addlinespace
        So49486&    2449328.27 &    12/06/1993& 18:23:43&   So49592&    2449335.75 &    14/12/1993& 05:42:29    \\

        So49487&    2449328.32 &    12/06/1993& 19:28:24&   Lo27048&    2449336.77 &    15/12/1993& 06:18:25    \\

        Lo26954&    2449328.56 &    12/07/1993& 01:16:10&   So49601&    2449336.79 &    15/12/1993& 06:46:47    \\

        Lo26971&    2449329.32 &    12/07/1993& 19:39:00&   &   &   &       \\

        \bottomrule      %inserts single line
        \end{tabular}
%    \end{adjustbox}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines shows page layout)

*Note*:
If your page layout is different, than may help to use smaller font size in table (for example `\small`) or further decrease `\arraystretch`.

Comment: I have tried and I am not getting the output you have given. I have left an image of the output using your code in the original question

Comment: Do you consider *note* in may answer? Apparently your page layout is different from used in my answer (which is based on guessing since you not provide any information about your document). Please, edit your question and extend your code fragment to an MWE!